# On MacOS I can't docker login if I have a special character in my password

Tags: macos, docker

Using Docker 20.10.12 on MacOS, I can't docker login  if I have a special character in my password. E.g. the last character is an '&'.

It reports:
`Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: exit status 1, out: status code not OK but 401: {"detail":"Incorrect authentication credentials"}`

Answer (score 8):

Modify $HOME/.docker/config.json to use the osxkeychain:

```
{
  "credsStore": "osxkeychain"
}
```

Shutdown Docker, restart Docker, login succeeds.

Comment: This is interesting behavior, and I can't imagine that it's intended. Have you considered filing this as a bug with the Docker team?